# OS X `rlwrap coqtop` not working

Tags: macos, homebrew, coq, coqide, rlwrap

`rlwrap` is a good program handling arrow keys in `REPL` loop. In most cases it works. For example `rlwrap sbcl`, `rlwrap sml`, and so on. But when it comes to `rlwrap coqtop`, it fails. The error information is below.

`rlwrap: error: Couldn't read completions from /usr/local/Cellar/rlwrap/0.41/share/rlwrap/completions/coqtop: No such file or directory`

I downloaded `coqide` from coq website, and installed `rlwrap` using `homebrew`. The file `/usr/local/Cellar/rlwrap/0.41/share/rlwrap/completions/coqtop` is at the right place. So, is there any clue how to fix this? Or is there a replacement software out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that [has been fixed](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/18) for the upcoming rlwrap 0.42.

If you don't want to wait for an upcoming release, you can always get the newest source from github (https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)

Comment: rlwrap 0.42 was released 14 nov 2014. This release fixes your problem